# "General RAII" class calling a lambda in its destructor

Tags: c++

I wrote a class that calls a lambda in its constructor:

```
template<typename Lambda>
class scope_guard
{
public:

    scope_guard(const Lambda & f, bool e = true) : free(f), engaged(e)
    {
    }

    scope_guard(const scope_guard &) = delete;

    scope_guard & operator = (const scope_guard &) = delete;

    scope_guard(scope_guard && other) : free(std::move(other.free))
    {
        other.engaged = false;
    }

    scope_guard & operator = (scope_guard && other)
    {
        free = std::move(other.free);
        other.engaged = false;
    }

    ~scope_guard()
    {
        if (engaged)
        {
            free();
        }
    }

    void release()
    {
        engaged = false;
    }

private:

    Lambda free;

    bool engaged = true;
};

template <class Lambda>
inline scope_guard<Lambda> make_scope_guard(const Lambda & free, bool engaged = true)
{
    return scope_guard<Lambda>(free, engaged);
}


template <class Init, class Free>
inline scope_guard<Free> make_scope_guard(const Init & init, const Free & free, bool engaged = true)
{
    if (engaged)
    {
        init();
    }

    return make_scope_guard(free, engaged);
}
```

but I am not sure is it smart enough to use this class in my code. Is it a good idea to use this class for restoring OpenGL state like this, for example?

```
{
    const bool enableDepthTest = IsDepthTestEnabledHere();
    auto guard = awl::make_scope_guard(
        []() { glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); },
        []() { glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); },
        enableDepthTest);

    //do OpenGL drawing here
}
```

of cause I am asking not only about OpenGL, but, in general, if something is set and should be unset when control leaves a block why not to use this class? At least it is useful when I have this general mechanism and do not need to write a separate class setting depth test on/off or depth mask on/off etc.. And of cause this class is not a replacement for existing RAII classes like std::unique_ptr.

Comment: At first glance it seems ok, but you should definitely add a try..catch statement in your d'tor to avoid any unexpected exceptions thrown from your lambdas. I would also block both assignment and move operators since you don't usually copy such objects as they are limited to a tightly defined scope as it is.

Comment: What will happen if there is no try/catch in destructor?

Comment: This seems to be very similar to [`Boost.ScopeExit`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: @Dmitriano, you are executing free code, and it is best practice to wrap such execution flows with a try..catch statement to avoid unexpected exceptions. If you want this to be a common module in a project, it should be easy to use, and as such, you and other programmers should have the minimal amount of constrains when using it. One such constrain is limiting this class to non-throwing lambdas.

Comment: @Daniel Adding a try/catch only mask potential problems...If your lambd throw, then your ressour e is not properly freed and and it might cause any future access to that resource to fail because it is still in use.

Comment: Lambda approach is good if your lambda is used only a few time in your application... In a case like the above one, I would probably do a specific class if I have to do that many times.

Comment: @Phil1970, avoiding try catch clauses because you are afraid of masking is a bad idea in my opinion. You should use `assert()`-s or log it appropriately instead of giving up on sufficient error handling. And your second suggestion is a good one (hard code cleanup code for common scenarios)!